# webdriver.chrome not working when express VPN is connected

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the below issue -

**Environment**
Chrome version - Version 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
chrome driver - ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22 (downloaded from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
python 3.6.6 32 bit
selenium - 3.141.0
ExpressVPN connected
Windows 10 Pro 64 bit system

**Code**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
```

Execution output

```
    D:\Assignment>python add_to_cart_v3.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59948/devtools/browser/b3bea32b-25a1-47ff-800c-162e0200566a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_to_cart_v3.py", line 67, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

When I disconnect the Express VPN, it works fine.
Please share your inputs about what could be the issue here.

Comment: Is Firefox an option?

Comment: No only chrome is to be used.

Comment: @Jortega Same problem is seen with Firefox as well

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Users\pc\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\win64\v0.27.0\geckodriver.exe

Comment: Try removing this line `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options` and this part `options=options,`.  Firefox on Express VPN works for me without those lines.
I am also on Window with Python version 3.8.3.

Comment: Tried with the above changes, still not working, also moved to python 3.6 64 bit, then also not working.

Comment: @Jortega what is the protocol u r using with ExpressVPN and what about the firewall settings. please share. Do you recommend to upgrade python 3.8

Comment: The reported issue is not seen when using Python 3.8.3 64 bit instead. All other environment parameters same (including the selenium version as 3.141.0)

Comment: so you upgraded to Python version 3.8.3 and the issue is resolved? Add and solution as an answer to this question.  This is an odd scenario.

Comment: yes @Jortega. I raised [this defect](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8803) too for which verification is in progress on python 3.6. I will add a complete answer with both python 3.8 and 3.6 once verification for that defect is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8803) defect, the issue is fixed for python 3.6 (will be released soon as part of python selenium release - check [here](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#history) for the status). Meanwhile if the environment is upgraded to python 3.8.3 64 bit, the issue is no longer seen (keep rest of the environment parameters same as reported in the problem statement)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have the same issue with surfshark but this fixed.
install `webdriver_manager` using pip.
with webdriver_manager there is no need to download chromedriver it automatically detects your chrome version.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
```

Comment: Same issue observed.

[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 86.0.4240
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 86.0.4240
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\pc\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\86.0.4240.22\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
-
-
-
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Comment: someone please share your inputs.